# How can I close/hide the Android soft keyboard programmatically?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard, android-input-method, soft-keyboard

I have an `EditText` and a `Button` in my layout.

After writing in the edit field and clicking on the `Button`, I want to hide the virtual keyboard when touching outside the keyboard. I assume that this is a simple piece of code, but where can I find an example of it?

Comment: What if you have only one EditText and several buttons, like check boxes and radios? The only place you need the keyboard is in the single EditText. How do you register to know that something else was chosen/clicked in order to hide the keyboard?

Comment: i feel stupid. I am unable to hide the keyboard on ICS. Tried all methods here and combinations of them.  No way. The method to show it works, but I cant hide it no matter what windw token, hide flags, manifest settings or candles to any saints. On keyboard show I always see this: 
    I/LatinIME(  396): InputType.TYPE_NULL is specified
    W/LatinIME(  396): Unexpected input class: inputType=0x00000000 imeOptions=0x00000000

Comment: /**
  * This method is used to hide soft keyboard.
  * @param activity
  */
 public void hideSoftKeyboard(Activity activity) {
  InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager)activity.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
  inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(activity.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
 }

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16184703/unable-to-hide-the-virtual-keyboard-of-searchview-iconfiedbydefaultfalse?answertab=votes#tab-top) worked for me

Comment: Need to play with InputMethodManager with the INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE to handle soft keyboard like https://readyandroid.wordpress.com/show-hide-android-soft-keyboard/

Comment: Are you serious with that? Can't simply hide the keybord at any point just if you want to? It doesn't mater if you have many buttons, or text, or a huge screen, to ask Android to hide keybord must be a single instruction :S

Comment: Try using InputMethodManager to handle the keyboard. Can try following this article.
https://androidacademic.blogspot.com/2023/02/closehide-android-soft-keyboard.html

Comment: to do this physically on the device when the keyboard is showing you can just hit the back button. is that an option in your program? edit - lol this question is so old! my b!

Answer (score 2568, accepted):

To help clarify this madness, I'd like to begin by apologizing on behalf of all Android users for Google's downright ridiculous treatment of the soft keyboard. The reason there are so many answers, each different, for the same simple question is that this API, like many others in Android, is horribly designed. I can think of no polite way to state it.

I want to hide the keyboard.  I expect to provide Android with the following statement: `Keyboard.hide()`. The end. Thank you very much.  But Android has a problem.  You must use the `InputMethodManager` to hide the keyboard. OK, fine, this is Android's API to the keyboard. BUT! You are required to have a `Context` in order to get access to the IMM. Now we have a problem.  I may want to hide the keyboard from a static or utility class that has no use or need for any `Context`. or And FAR worse, the IMM requires that you specify what `View` (or even worse, what `Window`) you want to hide the keyboard FROM.

This is what makes hiding the keyboard so challenging. Dear Google: When I'm looking up the recipe for a cake, there is no `RecipeProvider` on Earth that would refuse to provide me with the recipe unless I first answer WHO the cake will be eaten by AND where it will be eaten!!

This sad story ends with the ugly truth: to hide the Android keyboard, you will be required to provide 2 forms of identification: a `Context` and either a `View` or a `Window`.

I have created a static utility method that can do the job VERY solidly, provided you call it from an `Activity`.

```
public static void hideKeyboard(Activity activity) {
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    //Find the currently focused view, so we can grab the correct window token from it.
    View view = activity.getCurrentFocus();
    //If no view currently has focus, create a new one, just so we can grab a window token from it
    if (view == null) {
        view = new View(activity);
    }
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

Be aware that this utility method ONLY works when called from an `Activity`! The above method calls `getCurrentFocus` of the target `Activity` to fetch the proper window token.

But suppose you want to hide the keyboard from an `EditText` hosted in a `DialogFragment`? You can't use the method above for that:

```
hideKeyboard(getActivity()); //won't work
```

This won't work because you'll be passing a reference to the `Fragment`'s host `Activity`, which will have no focused control while the `Fragment` is shown! Wow! So, for hiding the keyboard from fragments, I resort to the lower-level, more common, and uglier:

```
public static void hideKeyboardFrom(Context context, View view) {
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

Below is some additional information gleaned from more time wasted chasing this solution:

**About windowSoftInputMode**

There's yet another point of contention to be aware of. By default, Android will automatically assign initial focus to the first `EditText` or focusable control in your `Activity`.  It naturally follows that the InputMethod (typically the soft keyboard) will respond to the focus event by showing itself. The `windowSoftInputMode` attribute in `AndroidManifest.xml`, when set to `stateAlwaysHidden`, instructs the keyboard to ignore this automatically-assigned initial focus.

```
<activity
    android:name=".MyActivity"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"/>
```

Almost unbelievably, it appears to do nothing to prevent the keyboard from opening when you touch the control (unless `focusable="false"` and/or `focusableInTouchMode="false"` are assigned to the control). Apparently, the windowSoftInputMode setting applies only to automatic focus events, not to focus events triggered by touch events.

Therefore, `stateAlwaysHidden` is VERY poorly named indeed. It should perhaps be called `ignoreInitialFocus` instead.

---

**UPDATE: More ways to get a window token**

If there is no focused view (e.g. can happen if you just changed fragments), there are other views that will supply a useful window token.

These are alternatives for the above code `if (view == null)   view = new View(activity);`  These don't refer explicitly to your activity.

Inside a fragment class:

```
view = getView().getRootView().getWindowToken();
```

Given a fragment `fragment` as a parameter:

```
view = fragment.getView().getRootView().getWindowToken();
```

Starting from your content body:

```
view = findViewById(android.R.id.content).getRootView().getWindowToken();
```

---

**UPDATE 2: Clear focus to avoid showing keyboard again if you open the app from the background**

Add this line to the end of the method:

`view.clearFocus();`

Comment: Why need `getRootView()` , why not `getView()` only?

Comment: One liner: `((InputMethodManager)getContext().getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).hideSoftInputFromWindow(getView().getWindowToken(), 0);`

Comment: Recently we finally got an official, backwards compatible way [to do this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67637849)

Comment: Finally there is an official way https://stackoverflow.com/a/67683124/4985958

Comment: I have one problem with this. The text inside the EditText field stays underlined as if the keyboard's suggestions were still active.

Comment: @Marcell sounds like the EditText is retaining focus. The ONLY way I know to remove focus from an input is to manually assign focus to anything else.

Comment: @SergeyChilingaryan It is not official and it is not working properly on some versions as you can see on the answer. On top of that, at least, one method has been deprecated now.

Comment: Hello, when the keyboard showed up on the screen I just went into the keyboard settings and unticked the "Show keyboard" box - that solved it for me. Hope it helps

Comment: `Be aware that this utility method ONLY works when called from an Activity! `
I save the top Activity onResume and onCreate into a global variable (kotlin): `var myPageTop = WeakReference<ComponentActivity>(null)`
Then you can do whatever you want without passing context around. The best way to solve this kind of dependency problem is to use global variable.

Answer (score 4709):

You can force Android to hide the virtual keyboard using the [InputMethodManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputMethodManager.html), calling [`hideSoftInputFromWindow`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputMethodManager.html#hideSoftInputFromWindow%28android.os.IBinder,%20int%29), passing in the token of the window containing your focused view.

```java
// Check if no view has focus:
View view = this.getCurrentFocus();
if (view != null) {  
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

This will force the keyboard to be hidden in all situations. In some cases, you will want to pass in `InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY` as the second parameter to ensure you only hide the keyboard when the user didn't explicitly force it to appear (by holding down the menu).

**Note:** If you want to do this in Kotlin, use:
`context?.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager`

**Kotlin Syntax**

```kotlin
// Only runs if there is a view that is currently focused
this.currentFocus?.let { view ->
    val imm = getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as? InputMethodManager
    imm?.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.windowToken, 0)
}
```

Comment: now `getSystemService()` requires a `Context` and a  serviceClass `Class`. For the context I can call `requiredContext` but what about for the serviceClass?

Comment: @capo11 I tried with Application.Context.getSystemService(), so I didn't need the serviceClass, but it doesn't work

Comment: Works well for me inside a `Fragment` using `getActivity().getSystemService()...`

Answer (score 855):

Also useful for hiding the soft-keyboard is:

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN
);
```

This can be used to suppress the soft-keyboard until the user actually touches the editText View.

Comment: This was the only one that worked for in 2020. I have a edit text on the main activity and don't want the keyboard to come up when starting the app.

Comment: Try using InputMethodManager to handle the keyboard. Can try following this article.
https://androidacademic.blogspot.com/2023/02/closehide-android-soft-keyboard.html

Answer (score 389):

I got one more solution to hide keyboard:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY, 0);
```

Here pass `HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY` at the position of `showFlag` and `0` at the position of `hiddenFlag`. It will forcefully close soft Keyboard.

Comment: You're using a hide flag in the showflags parameter. This only works because the constants use the same integers. [Example using the correct flags](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15587937/197359)

Comment: @Mark: Because the method is called "toggleSoftInput", not "hideSoftInput" :)

Comment: This doesn't work correctly. It some times shows the keyboard.

Answer (score 170):

Meier's solution works for me too. In my case, the top level of my App is a tab host and I want to hide the keyword when switching tabs - I get the window token from the tab host View.

```
tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener() {
    public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(tabHost.getApplicationWindowToken(), 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 166):

Please try this below code in  `onCreate()`

```
EditText edtView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextConvertValue);
edtView.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
```

Comment: This method works as a means of getting around the "can't hide the soft keyboard" bug in 2.0 and 2.1 as described in http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=7115 ... the hideSoftInputFromWindow method listed above did not work when I tried it, but editView.setInputType(0) did.

Comment: This is legit per Javadoc (not a hack) though I would rewrite the method as `editView.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);`

Comment: this works, however, it hides the android:hint. i'm using Android 1.5

Comment: It works, but it's also hiding the cursor. I need the cursor, but no system keyboard.

Comment: Second part of the answer was copied from another answer. Revision was rolled back.

Answer (score 157):

**Update:**
I don't know why this solution is not work any more ( I just tested on Android 23). Please use the solution of [Saurabh Pareek](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9494042/523325) instead. Here it is:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
//Hide:
imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY, 0);
//Show
imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT, 0);
```

Old answer:

```
//Show soft-keyboard:
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
//hide keyboard :
 getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

Comment: Where should i place this code? I've tried to paste  getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN); in onCreate() but the keyboard is never hidden

Comment: does not work, tested in radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener, API 23

Comment: If you look closer, InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY and InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT have the same value, which is "1", so there is no difference between these calls. => not working

Comment: if calling imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY, 0); then keyboard will show on screen :) Best implementation is: https://github.com/ravindu1024/android-keyboardlistener Shame on Android SDK

Comment: `I don't know why this solution is not work any more` - because it's ***Android***, everything will be able to change, maybe partly of bad design... We write carelessly, then we strike out all and rewrite everything.

Comment: Working, but actually makes the keyboard VISIBLE on almost all SAMSUNG devices :) I love Android.

Comment: Check this out for answer https://medium.com/p/a111cffb8704

Answer (score 104):

```
protected void hideSoftKeyboard(EditText input) {
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(input.getWindowToken(), 0);    
}
```

Comment: This worked for me! But why did you put **input.setInputType(0)** ? I couldn't interact with the _EditTextView_ when I had that line of code (It worked when I removed it).

Comment: Probably `input.getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)`.

Comment: I removed `input.setInputType(0);` from this code. It changed a keyboard behaviour and `inputType` for the `EditText`.

Answer (score 88):

If all the other answers here don't work for you as you would like them to, there's another way of manually controlling the keyboard.

Create a function with that will manage some of the `EditText`'s properties:

```
public void setEditTextFocus(boolean isFocused) {
    searchEditText.setCursorVisible(isFocused);
    searchEditText.setFocusable(isFocused);
    searchEditText.setFocusableInTouchMode(isFocused);

    if (isFocused) {
        searchEditText.requestFocus();
    }
}
```

Then, make sure that onFocus of the `EditText` you open/close the keyboard:

```
searchEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (v == searchEditText) {
            if (hasFocus) {
                // Open keyboard
                ((InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).showSoftInput(searchEditText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);
            } else {
                // Close keyboard
                ((InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).hideSoftInputFromWindow(searchEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Now, whenever you want to open the keyboard manually call:

```
setEditTextFocus(true);
```

And for closing call:

```
setEditTextFocus(false);
```

Comment: I got 'Cannot resolve symbol context', on 7th and 10th line of second block of code.

Comment: Use getContext() instead

Comment: Context context = View.getContext();

Answer (score 73):

[Saurabh Pareek](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9494042/197359) has the best answer so far.

Might as well use the correct flags, though.

```
/* hide keyboard */
((InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE))
    .toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT, 0);

/* show keyboard */
((InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE))
    .toggleSoftInput(0, InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
```

Example of real use

```
/* click button */
public void onClick(View view) {      
  /* hide keyboard */
  ((InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE))
      .toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT, 0);

  /* start loader to check parameters ... */
}

/* loader finished */
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Object> loader, Object data) {
    /* parameters not valid ... */

    /* show keyboard */
    ((InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE))
        .toggleSoftInput(0, InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);

    /* parameters valid ... */
}
```

Answer (score 66):

from so searching, here I found an answer that works for me

```
// Show soft-keyboard:
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);

// Hide soft-keyboard:
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

Answer (score 64):

### The short answer

In your `OnClick` listener call the `onEditorAction` of the `EditText` with `IME_ACTION_DONE`

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        someEditText.onEditorAction(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE)
    }
});
```

### The drill-down

I feel this method is better, simpler and more aligned with Android's design pattern.
In the simple example above (and usually in most of the common cases) you'll have an `EditText` that has/had focus and it also usually was the one to invoke the keyboard in the first place (it is definitely able to invoke it in many common scenarios). In that same way, **it** should be the one to release the keyboard, usually that can be done by an `ImeAction`. Just see how an `EditText` with `android:imeOptions="actionDone"` behaves, you want to achieve the same behavior by the same means.

---

Check this [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3449616/2837443)

Answer (score 50):

This should work:

```
public class KeyBoard {

    public static void show(Activity activity){
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.toggleSoftInput(0, InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY); // show
    }

    public static void hide(Activity activity){
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY, 0); // hide
    }

    public static void toggle(Activity activity){
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        if (imm.isActive()){
            hide(activity); 
        } else {
            show(activity); 
        }
    }
}

KeyBoard.toggle(activity);
```

Comment: @YoushaAleayoub yes it will.

`KeyBoard.toggle(fragment.getActivity())`

Comment: @slinden77, lol, I'm talking about your Answer... not this one you have commented. So that answer still WONT work.

Comment: @YoushaAleayoub uhm yes it will. The original question doesn't mention fragments, you are the one who mentioned fragments. So my answer is perfectly valid. To use it with fragments, call the method differently from a `Fragment`, like a commented. Learn how to use methods please and then come back. You're confusing people with your silly replies

Answer (score 49):

I'm using a custom keyboard to input an Hex number so I can't have the IMM keyboard show up...

In v3.2.4_r1 `setSoftInputShownOnFocus(boolean show)` was added to control weather or not to display the keyboard when a TextView gets focus, but its still hidden so reflection must be used:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2) {
    try {
        Method method = TextView.class.getMethod("setSoftInputShownOnFocus", boolean.class);
        method.invoke(mEditText, false);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Fallback to the second method
    }
}
```

---

For older versions, I got very good results (but far from perfect) with a `OnGlobalLayoutListener`, added with the aid of a `ViewTreeObserver` from my root view and then checking if the keyboard is shown like this:

```
@Override
public void onGlobalLayout() {
    Configuration config = getResources().getConfiguration();

    // Dont allow the default keyboard to show up
    if (config.keyboardHidden != Configuration.KEYBOARDHIDDEN_YES) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(mRootView.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
}
```

This last solution may show the keyboard for a split second and messes with the selection handles.

When in the keyboard enters full screen, onGlobalLayout isn't called. To avoid that, use [TextView#setImeOptions(int)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setImeOptions%28int%29) or in the TextView XML declaration:

```
android:imeOptions="actionNone|actionUnspecified|flagNoFullscreen|flagNoExtractUi"
```

**Update:** Just found what dialogs use to never show the keyboard and works in all versions:

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM);
```

Comment: Cool solution, however, if your front activity is not fullscreen, the keyboard is visible behind it. Also the keyboard's cursor movement aid is also still visible. And it's not skinnable.

Comment: I second that. Of all the possible ways only the getWindow().setFlags() method works, at least on stock Android 5.1. Note that setSoftInputShownOnFocus() is now setShowSoftInputOnFocus() and no longer hidden but does not work, at least not when the user touches the field.

Answer (score 49):

Thank God it’s officially supported [after 11 years](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=acC7SR1EXsI).

First add dependency `implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'` to app gradle.

Then get InsetsController from ViewCompat or WindowCompat class.

Finally use hide() and show() function of InsetsController

Add support for Dialog. Available in BottomSheetDialog. @Rondev.
Using a safer way to get activity instead of directly cast from context.

```
import android.app.Activity
import android.app.Dialog
import android.content.Context
import android.content.ContextWrapper
import android.view.View
import androidx.core.view.ViewCompat
import androidx.core.view.WindowCompat
import androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsCompat
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment

fun View.showKeyboard() = ViewCompat.getWindowInsetsController(this)?.show(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.ime())
fun View.hideKeyboard() = ViewCompat.getWindowInsetsController(this)?.hide(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.ime())

fun Dialog.showKeyboard() = window?.decorView?.showKeyboard()
fun Dialog.hideKeyboard() = window?.decorView?.hideKeyboard()

fun Context.showKeyboard() = getActivity()?.showKeyboard()
fun Context.hideKeyboard() = getActivity()?.hideKeyboard()

fun Fragment.showKeyboard() = activity?.showKeyboard()
fun Fragment.hideKeyboard() = activity?.hideKeyboard()

fun Activity.showKeyboard() = WindowCompat.getInsetsController(window, window.decorView)?.show(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.ime())
fun Activity.hideKeyboard() = WindowCompat.getInsetsController(window, window.decorView)?.hide(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.ime())

fun Context.getActivity(): Activity? {
    return when (this) {
        is Activity -> this
        is ContextWrapper -> this.baseContext.getActivity()
        else -> null
    }
}
```

**Old anwser below**

**Here is the simple [project](https://github.com/sergchil/KeyboardTest) on github**

```
import android.app.Activity
import android.app.Dialog
import android.content.Context
import android.content.ContextWrapper
import android.view.View
import androidx.core.view.ViewCompat
import androidx.core.view.WindowCompat
import androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsCompat
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment

fun View.showKeyboard() = ViewCompat.getWindowInsetsController(this)?.show(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.ime())
fun View.hideKeyboard() = ViewCompat.getWindowInsetsController(this)?.hide(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.ime())

fun Dialog.showKeyboard() = window?.decorView?.showKeyboard()
fun Dialog.hideKeyboard() = window?.decorView?.hideKeyboard()

fun Context.showKeyboard() = getActivity()?.showKeyboard()
fun Context.hideKeyboard() = getActivity()?.hideKeyboard()

fun Fragment.showKeyboard() = activity?.showKeyboard()
fun Fragment.hideKeyboard() = activity?.hideKeyboard()

fun Activity.showKeyboard() = WindowCompat.getInsetsController(window, window.decorView)?.show(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.ime())
fun Activity.hideKeyboard() = WindowCompat.getInsetsController(window, window.decorView)?.hide(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.ime())

fun Context.getActivity(): Activity? {
    return when (this) {
        is Activity -> this
        is ContextWrapper -> this.baseContext.getActivity()
        else -> null
    }
}
```

Comment: Requires API level 31

Comment: @Johann For compatibility, use WindowCompat and WindowInsetsControllerCompat. You'll need to upgrade your gradle dependency for androidx.core to at least 1.6.0-alpha03 so that there will be support on SDK < 30.

Comment: @Johann take a look at the sample project https://github.com/sergchil/KeyboardTest

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't get the hide function to work inside a `BottomSheetDialogFragment`

Comment: @Rondev That is because dialogs run in their own window. Instead, you can do `dialog?.window` instead.

Comment: getWindowInsetsController is deprecated

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/view/ViewCompat#getWindowInsetsController(android.view.View) says "This method is deprecated.
Prefer getInsetsController to explicitly specify the window (such as when the view is in a dialog)." Which means that we're back to specifying a window as well as a view, even though we may be in a place where we don't know or care about either one.

Answer (score 38):

```
public void setKeyboardVisibility(boolean show) {
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    if(show){
        imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
    }else{
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(),0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 36):

Now, almost 12 years later, we finally have an official, backwards compatible way to do this with [AndroidX Core 1.5+](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/core#1.5.0):

```
fun View.hideKeyboard() = ViewCompat.getWindowInsetsController(this)
    ?.hide(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.ime())
```

or specifically for Fragment:

```
fun Fragment.hideKeyboard() = ViewCompat.getWindowInsetsController(requireView())
    ?.hide(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.ime())
```

Comment: Well would you look at that! Of course, it had to involve yet another API (window insets controller vs input method manager), but hey, at least the word 'hide' is there.

Comment: If you want to hide the keyboard but only have a reference to the Activity, which view should you use? `window.decorView`?  Before, you would get the windowToken with `currentFocus?.windowToken` and then use `InputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(windowToken, 0)`

Comment: @Mark, good question! Testing shows that `window.decorView` does not work on API 25-29: `ViewCompat.getWindowInsetsController()` returns `null`. `currentFocus` has a similar problem on API 30. But you can use any view in your layout, e.g. its root view. For hiding keyboard it works, but for showing keyboard you might be better off with some `EditText`: `WindowInsetsControllerCompat.show()` uses it to request focus.

Comment: Thanks @gmk57 So how about using `currentFocus` pre-30, and `window.decorView` 30+?

Comment: That might work, but in any case you will have to test it thoroughly. Behavior might depend on device manufacturer, your specific widgets layout and other factors. For example, on one of my devices [this method to show keyboard](https://developer.squareup.com/blog/showing-the-android-keyboard-reliably/) works well with GBoard, but disables SwiftKey completely. This is Android. :(

Comment: @gmk57 good to know thanks. So it sounds like it would be better to use a View in the activity's View hierarchy (usually I have access to `SomeBinding.root`). From a `Fragment`, just use `view?.hideKeyboard()`. However, I'm not seeing any benefit over using `context.getSystemService<InputMethodManager>()?.hideSoftInputFromWindow(windowToken, 0)`

Comment: I've rolled back changes by @hb0 because ViewCompat already includes that SDK version check. Even its name implies "backwards compatibility". ;)

Comment: In [Kotlin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kotlin_(programming_language))?

Answer (score 33):

I have spent more than two days working through all of the solutions posted in the thread and have found them lacking in one way or another.  My exact requirement is to have a button that will with 100% reliability show or hide the on screen keyboard.  When the keyboard is in its hidden state is should not re-appear, no matter what input fields the user clicks on.  When it is in its visible state the keyboard should not disappear no matter what buttons the user clicks.  This needs to work on Android 2.2+ all the way up to the latest devices.

You can see a working implementation of this in my app [clean RPN](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=au.com.lukesleeman.rpn&hl=en).

After testing many of the suggested answers on a number of different phones (including froyo and gingerbread devices) it became apparent that android apps can reliably:

1. Temporarily hide the keyboard.  It will re-appear again when a user
   focuses a new text field.
2. Show the keyboard when an activity starts
   and set a flag on the activity indicating that they keyboard should
   always be visible.  This flag can only be set when an activity is
   initialising.
3. Mark an activity to never show or allow the use of the
   keyboard.  This flag can only be set when an activity is
   initialising.

For me, temporarily hiding the keyboard is not enough.  On some devices it will re-appear as soon as a new text field is focused.  As my app uses multiple text fields on one page, focusing a new text field will cause the hidden keyboard to pop back up again.

Unfortunately item 2 and 3 on the list only work reliability when an activity is being started.  Once the activity has become visible you cannot permanently hide or show the keyboard.  The trick is to actually restart your activity when the user presses the keyboard toggle button.  In my app when the user presses on the toggle keyboard button, the following code runs:

```
private void toggleKeyboard(){

    if(keypadPager.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
        Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
        Bundle state = new Bundle();
        onSaveInstanceState(state);
        state.putBoolean(SHOW_KEYBOARD, true);
        i.putExtras(state);

        startActivity(i);
    }
    else{
        Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
        Bundle state = new Bundle();
        onSaveInstanceState(state);
        state.putBoolean(SHOW_KEYBOARD, false);
        i.putExtras(state);

        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

This causes the current activity to have its state saved into a Bundle, and then the activity is started, passing through an boolean which indicates if the keyboard should be shown or hidden.

Inside the onCreate method the following code is run:

```
if(bundle.getBoolean(SHOW_KEYBOARD)){
    ((InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).showSoftInput(newEquationText,0);
    getWindow().setSoftInputMode(LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
}
else{
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM);
}
```

If the soft keyboard should be shown, then the InputMethodManager is told to show the keyboard and the window is instructed to make the soft input always visible. If the soft keyboard should be hidden then the WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM is set.

This approach works reliably on all devices I have tested on - from a 4 year old HTC phone running android 2.2 up to a nexus 7 running 4.2.2.  The only disadvantage with this approach is you need to be careful with handling the back button.  As my app essentially only has one screen (its a calculator) I can override onBackPressed() and return to the devices home screen.

Comment: elaborate workaround, but i think it's just too much , to recreate thousands of objects just to hide the Keyboard. I dont know who designed the IMM for android, but it smells like a Windows APi. In my opinion, a good IME should have two methods: hide and show :-)

Comment: Its all true, but my workaround does have one advantage - it always works!  There is no other solution I could find that would always toggle the keyboard, regardless of of what fields in the UI have the focus, what the user has done to toggle and keyboard and what version of android they are running :-\

Comment: Man, I'm totally desperate to hide the keyboard. Tried thousands of things and noooone works. But your workaround is too much for me, I'd have to recreate like 10 fragments, initialize services, delete a lot of WeakReferences .... you know? the GC would just throw away like 25mb :S ... Still looking for a reliable way to do it :(

Comment: @Dmitry well it's not a hello world...it's a complex application for tablets. I refuse to totally unload it from memory just to hide a silly keyboard... Anyway I found something that works combining the thousand solutions proposed here :)

Answer (score 31):

Alternatively to [this all around solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9494042/451962), if you wanted to close the soft keyboard **from anywhere** without having a reference to the (EditText) field that was used to open the keyboard, but still wanted to do it if the field was focused, you could use this (from an Activity):

```
if (getCurrentFocus() != null) {
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

Answer (score 26):

Thanks to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7696791/1617737), I derived the following which, in my case, works nicely when scrolling through the the fragments of a ViewPager...

```
private void hideKeyboard() {   
    // Check if no view has focus:
    View view = this.getCurrentFocus();
    if (view != null) {
        InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) this.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
    }
}

private void showKeyboard() {   
    // Check if no view has focus:
    View view = this.getCurrentFocus();
    if (view != null) {
        InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) this.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputManager.showSoftInput(view, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 22):

Above answers work for different scenario's but  **If you want to hide the keyboard inside a view and struggling to get the right context try this:**

```
setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        hideSoftKeyBoardOnTabClicked(v);
    }
}

private void hideSoftKeyBoardOnTabClicked(View v) {
    if (v != null && context != null) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getApplicationWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
    }
}
```

and to get the context fetch it from constructor:)

```
public View/RelativeLayout/so and so (Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    this.context = context;
    init();
}
```

Answer (score 21):

If you want to close the soft keyboard during a unit or functional test, you can do so by clicking the "back button" from your test:

```
// Close the soft keyboard from a Test
getInstrumentation().sendKeyDownUpSync(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK);
```

I put "back button" in quotes, since the above doesn't trigger the `onBackPressed()` for the Activity in question. It just closes the keyboard.

Make sure to pause for a little while before moving on, since it takes a little while to close the back button, so subsequent clicks to Views, etc., won't be registered until after a short pause (1 second is long enough ime).

Answer (score 18):

Here's how you do it in Mono for Android (AKA MonoDroid)

```
InputMethodManager imm = GetSystemService (Context.InputMethodService) as InputMethodManager;
if (imm != null)
    imm.HideSoftInputFromWindow (searchbox.WindowToken , 0);
```

Comment: What is `searchbox` in the snippet?

Answer (score 17):

This worked for me for all the bizarre keyboard behavior

```
private boolean isKeyboardVisible() {
    Rect r = new Rect();
    //r will be populated with the coordinates of your view that area still visible.
    mRootView.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r);

    int heightDiff = mRootView.getRootView().getHeight() - (r.bottom - r.top);
    return heightDiff > 100; // if more than 100 pixels, its probably a keyboard...
}

protected void showKeyboard() {
    if (isKeyboardVisible())
        return;
    InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    if (getCurrentFocus() == null) {
        inputMethodManager.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
    } else {
        View view = getCurrentFocus();
        inputMethodManager.showSoftInput(view, InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);
    }
}

protected void hideKeyboard() {
    if (!isKeyboardVisible())
        return;
    InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    View view = getCurrentFocus();
    if (view == null) {
        if (inputMethodManager.isAcceptingText())
            inputMethodManager.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS, 0);
    } else {
        if (view instanceof EditText)
            ((EditText) view).setText(((EditText) view).getText().toString()); // reset edit text bug on some keyboards bug
        inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromInputMethod(view.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is mRootView?

Answer (score 16):

Simple and Easy to use method, just call **hideKeyboardFrom(YourActivity.this);** to hide keyboard

```
/**
 * This method is used to hide keyboard
 * @param activity
 */
public static void hideKeyboardFrom(Activity activity) {
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(activity.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

Comment: You didn't check whether `activity.getCurrentFocus()` was null, it could well be if the keyboard was actually not visible

Answer (score 16):

#### Kotlin version via an extension function

Using Kotlin extension functions, it'd be so simple to show and hide the soft keyboard.

**ExtensionFunctions.kt**

```
import android.app.Activity
import android.view.View
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager
import android.widget.EditText
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment

fun Activity.hideKeyboard(): Boolean {
    return (getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager)
        .hideSoftInputFromWindow((currentFocus ?: View(this)).windowToken, 0)
}

fun Fragment.hideKeyboard(): Boolean {
    return (context?.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager)
        .hideSoftInputFromWindow((activity?.currentFocus ?: View(context)).windowToken, 0)
}

fun EditText.hideKeyboard(): Boolean {
    return (context.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager)
        .hideSoftInputFromWindow(windowToken, 0)
}

fun EditText.showKeyboard(): Boolean {
    return (context.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager)
        .showSoftInput(this, 0)
}
```

#### Usage

Now in your `Activity` or `Fragment`, `hideKeyboard()` is clearly accessible as well as calling it from an instance of `EditText` like:

```
editText.hideKeyboard()
```

Answer (score 15):

Just use this optimized code in your activity:

```
if (this.getCurrentFocus() != null) {
    InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) this.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(this.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
}
```

Answer (score 15):

Add to your activity    `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"` in Manifest file. Example:

```
<activity
            android:name=".ui.activity.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/mainactivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"/>
```

Answer (score 14):

I have the case, where my `EditText` can be located also in an `AlertDialog`, so the keyboard should be closed on dismiss. The following code seems to be working anywhere:

```
public static void hideKeyboard( Activity activity ) {
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)activity.getSystemService( Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE );
    View f = activity.getCurrentFocus();
    if( null != f && null != f.getWindowToken() && EditText.class.isAssignableFrom( f.getClass() ) )
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow( f.getWindowToken(), 0 );
    else 
        activity.getWindow().setSoftInputMode( WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN );
}
```

Comment: This solution is better because you have not to control which EditText pass as a parameter to hideSoftInputFromWindow() method. It works great!!

Answer (score 14):

For Open Keyboard :

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.showSoftInput(edtView, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

For Close/Hide Keyboard :

```
 InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
 imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(edtView.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Answer (score 14):

Works like magic touch every time

```
private void closeKeyboard() {
    InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getActivity().getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);

}

private void openKeyboard() {
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    if(imm != null){
        imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT, 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

```
public static void hideSoftKeyboard(Activity activity) {
    InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager)  activity.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(activity.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

after that call on onTouchListener:

```
findViewById(android.R.id.content).setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        Utils.hideSoftKeyboard(activity);
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Try this as well - this worked for me:  InputMethodManager imm = ((InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE));
 imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getWindow().getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);

Answer (score 12):

use this

```
this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

Answer (score 11):

For my case, I was using the a SearchView in the actionbar. After a user performs a search, the keyboard would pop open again.

Using the InputMethodManager did not close the keyboard. I had to clearFocus and set the focusable of the search view to false:

```
mSearchView.clearFocus();
mSearchView.setFocusable(false);
```

Comment: Very clever. If the user wants another search, just click search again.

Comment: SearchView does not have a `clearFocus()` in the Android API pages, so this did not work for me, but another solution did (see my answer below).

Comment: @Noni A, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7409288/how-to-dismiss-keyboard-in-android-searchview

Answer (score 11):

I have almost tried all of these answers, I had some random issues especially with the samsung galaxy s5.

What I end up with is forcing the show and hide, and it works perfectly:

```
/**
 * Force show softKeyboard.
 */
public static void forceShow(@NonNull Context context) {
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
}

/**
 * Force hide softKeyboard.
 */
public static void forceHide(@NonNull Activity activity, @NonNull EditText editText) {
    if (activity.getCurrentFocus() == null || !(activity.getCurrentFocus() instanceof EditText)) {
        editText.requestFocus();
    }
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editText.getWindowToken(), 0);
    activity.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
}
```

Answer (score 11):

In some cases this methods can works except of all others. 
This saves my day :)

```
public static void hideSoftKeyboard(Activity activity) {
    if (activity != null) {
        InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        if (activity.getCurrentFocus() != null && inputManager != null) {
            inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(activity.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
            inputManager.hideSoftInputFromInputMethod(activity.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
    }
}

public static void hideSoftKeyboard(View view) {
    if (view != null) {
        InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) view.getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        if (inputManager != null) {
            inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You could also look into using [setImeOption](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:imeOptions) on the EditText.

I just had a very simular situation where my layout contained an EditText and a search button.  When I discovered I could just set the ime option to "actionSearch" on my editText, I realized I didn't even need a search button anymore.  The soft keyboard (in this mode) has a search icon, which can be used to kick off the search (and the keyboard closes itself as you would expect).

Comment: is there some trick to making the keyboad auto close in this method? it's not doing so on jellybean. the edittext loses focus, but the keyboard doesn't hide.

Answer (score 8):

sometimes all you want is the enter button to fold the `keyboard`
give the `EditText` box you have the attribute

```
 android:imeOptions="actionDone"
```

this will change the Enter button to a Done button that will close the keyboard.

Comment: in my case, in addition to `android:imeOptions="actionDone"` also needed to include `android:singleLine="true"`

Answer (score 8):

Just call the below method. It will hide your keyboard if it’s showing.

```
public void hideKeyboard() {
    try {
        InputMethodManager inputmanager = (InputMethodManager)this.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        if (inputmanager != null) {
            inputmanager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(this.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
    } 
    catch (Exception var2) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

For Kotlin lovers. I have created two extension functions. For hideKeyboard fun, you can pass edittext's instance as a view.

```
fun Context.hideKeyboard(view: View) {
    (getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as? InputMethodManager)?.apply {
        hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.windowToken, 0)
    }
}

fun Context.showKeyboard() {
    (getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as? InputMethodManager)?.apply {
        toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Using [Android 10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_10), we are going to get an amazing way to show and hide keyboards. Read the [Release Notes - 1.5.0-alpha02](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/core#1.5.0-alpha02). Now how to hide or show the keyboard:

```
val controller = view.windowInsetsController

// Show the keyboard
controller.show(Type.ime())
// Hide the keyboard
controller.hide(Type.ime())
```

Linking my own answer [How to check visibility of software keyboard in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150078/how-to-check-visibility-of-software-keyboard-in-android/63595830#63595830) and an [Amazing blog which includes more of this change (even more than it)](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/animating-your-keyboard-fb776a8fb66d).

Comment: what is import for ```Type```?

Comment: @MichaelAbyzov This would be 'https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowInsets.Type', see more about the hide() method at  'https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/view/WindowInsetsController#hide(kotlin.Int)'

Answer (score 7):

So many of these answers are needlessly complex; here is a solution for Kotlin users to create a neat little extension function on the `View` class.

Create a basic Kotlin file (I've named mine `KeyboardUtil.kt`), and introduce the following:

```
fun View.hideKeyboard() {
  val imm = ContextCompat.getSystemService(context, InputMethodManager::class.java) as InputMethodManager
  imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(windowToken, 0)
}
```

Then, you can call this on any view to easily dismiss the keyboard. I use ViewBinding/DataBinding, and it works particularly well, for example:

```
fun submitForm() {
  binding.root.hideKeyboard()
  // continue now the keyboard is dismissed
}
```

Answer (score 6):

It works for me..

```
EditText editText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext1);
```

put below line of code in onClick()

```
editText.setFocusable(false);
editText.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
```

here hide the keyboard when we click the Button and when we touch the EditText keyboard will be display.

**(OR)**

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

Answer (score 6):

Sometime you can have an activity that contains a listview with rows that contains editText so you have to setup in manifest `SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN` then they keyboard shows up which is annoying.

The following workarround works if you place it at the end of `onCreate`

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
            }
        },100);
```

Answer (score 6):

In  `AndroidManifest.xml` under `<activity..>` set `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"`

Answer (score 6):

If you want to hide keyboard using Java code, then use this:

```
  InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)this.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
  imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(fEmail.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Or if you want to hide the keyboard always, then use this in your AndroidManifest:

```
 <activity
 android:name=".activities.MyActivity"
 android:configChanges="keyboardHidden"  />
```

Comment: The java code solution worked for me in a fragment when I replaced fEmail with the view that opened the keyboard.  It worked on Samsung Galaxy Tab S2 running Android 5.1.1, Nexus 5 running 6.0.1, and an XT1032 running 5.1 (This is using the support libraries.)

Answer (score 6):

## Try this

- Simple you can call in your `Activity`

---

```
 public static void hideKeyboardwithoutPopulate(Activity activity) {
    InputMethodManager inputMethodManager =
            (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(
                    Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(
            activity.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

---

- In your `MainActivitiy` call this

---

```
 hideKeyboardwithoutPopulate(MainActivity.this);
```

---

Answer (score 6):

this is Working..

Just Pass your current activity instance in the function

```
 public void isKeyBoardShow(Activity activity) {
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    if (imm.isActive()) {
        imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY, 0); // hide
    } else {
        imm.toggleSoftInput(0, InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY); // show
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I have written small extension for Kotlin if anyone interested, didn't test it much tho:

```
fun Fragment.hideKeyboard(context: Context = App.instance) {
    val windowToken = view?.rootView?.windowToken
    windowToken?.let {
        val imm = context.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(windowToken, 0)
    }
}
```

App.instance is static "this" Application object stored in Application

Update: In some cases windowToken is null. I have added additional way of closing keyboard using reflection to detect if keyboard is closed

```
/**
 * If no window token is found, keyboard is checked using reflection to know if keyboard visibility toggle is needed
 *
 * @param useReflection - whether to use reflection in case of no window token or not
 */
fun Fragment.hideKeyboard(context: Context = MainApp.instance, useReflection: Boolean = true) {
    val windowToken = view?.rootView?.windowToken
    val imm = context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
    windowToken?.let {
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(windowToken, 0)
    } ?: run {
        if (useReflection) {
            try {
                if (getKeyboardHeight(imm) > 0) {
                    imm.toggleSoftInput(0, InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS)
                }
            } catch (exception: Exception) {
                Timber.e(exception)
            }
        }
    }
}

fun getKeyboardHeight(imm: InputMethodManager): Int = InputMethodManager::class.java.getMethod("getInputMethodWindowVisibleHeight").invoke(imm) as Int
```

Answer (score 6):

If you use Kotlin for developing your application, it's really easy to do.

Add this extensions functions:

For Activity:

```
fun Activity.hideKeyboard() {
    val inputManager = getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
    val view = currentFocus
    if (view != null) {
        inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.windowToken, InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS)
    }
}
```

For Fragment:

```
fun Fragment.hideKeyboard() {
    activity?.let {
        val inputManager = it.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
        val view = it.currentFocus
        if (view != null) {
            inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.windowToken, InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS)
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can simple call in your Fragment or Activity:

```
 hideKeyboard()
```

Comment: instead of writing the same logic again just call activity?.hideKeyboard from your fragment implementation

Comment: Btw, the fragment implementation doesn't work as stated by community wiki. To get the correct windowToken you'll have to call val windowToken = view?.rootView?.windowToken

Answer (score 6):

#### A Kotlin solution in a fragment

```
fun hideSoftKeyboard() {
        val view = activity?.currentFocus
        view?.let { v ->
            val imm =
                activity?.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager // or context
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.windowToken, 0)
        }
}
```

Check your manifest doesn't have this parameter associated with your activity:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"
```

Answer (score 5):

Actually, always Android authority is giving new updates but they are not handling their old drawbacks which all Android developers face in their development this should be handled by Android authority by default, on changing focus from EditText should hide/show soft input keyboard option. But sorry about that, they are not managing. Ok, leave it.

Below are the solutions to show/hide/toggle a keyboard option in Activity or Fragment.

**Show keyboard for the view:**

```
/**
 * open soft keyboard.
 *
 * @param context
 * @param view
 */
public static void showKeyBoard(Context context, View view) {
    try {
        InputMethodManager keyboard = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        keyboard.showSoftInput(view, 0);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**Show keyboard with Activity context:**

```
/**
 * open soft keyboard.
 *
 * @param mActivity context
 */
public static void showKeyBoard(Activity mActivity) {
    try {
        View view = mActivity.getCurrentFocus();
        if (view != null) {
            InputMethodManager keyboard = (InputMethodManager) mActivity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            keyboard.showSoftInputFromInputMethod(view.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**Show keyboard with Fragment context:**

```
/**
 * open soft keyboard.
 *
 * @param mFragment context
 */
public static void showKeyBoard(Fragment mFragment) {
    try {
        if (mFragment == null || mFragment.getActivity() == null) {
            return;
        }
        View view = mFragment.getActivity().getCurrentFocus();
        if (view != null) {
            InputMethodManager keyboard = (InputMethodManager) mFragment.getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            keyboard.showSoftInputFromInputMethod(view.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**Hide keyboard for the view:**

```
/**
 * close soft keyboard.
 *
 * @param context
 * @param view
 */
public static void hideKeyBoard(Context context, View view) {
    try {
        InputMethodManager keyboard = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        keyboard.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**Hide keyboard with Activity context:**

```
/**
 * close opened soft keyboard.
 *
 * @param mActivity context
 */
public static void hideSoftKeyboard(Activity mActivity) {
    try {
        View view = mActivity.getCurrentFocus();
        if (view != null) {
            InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) mActivity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**Hide keyboard with Fragment context:**

```
/**
 * close opened soft keyboard.
 *
 * @param mFragment context
 */
public static void hideSoftKeyboard(Fragment mFragment) {
    try {
        if (mFragment == null || mFragment.getActivity() == null) {
            return;
        }
        View view = mFragment.getActivity().getCurrentFocus();
        if (view != null) {
            InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) mFragment.getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**Toggle Keyboard:**

```
/**
 * toggle soft keyboard.
 *
 * @param context
 */
public static void toggleSoftKeyboard(Context context) {
    try {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY, 0);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

In Kotlin

```
fun hideKeyboard(activity: BaseActivity) {
        val view = activity.currentFocus?: View(activity)
        val imm = activity.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.windowToken, 0)
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

Here are both hide & show methods.

### Kotlin

```
fun hideKeyboard(activity: Activity) {
    val v = activity.currentFocus
    val imm = activity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
    assert(v != null)
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v!!.windowToken, InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS)
}

private fun showKeyboard(activity: Activity) {
    val v = activity.currentFocus
    val imm = activity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
    assert(v != null)
    imm.showSoftInput(v, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT)
}
```

### Java

```
public static void hideKeyboard(Activity activity) {
    View v = activity.getCurrentFocus();
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    assert imm != null && v != null;
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
}

private static void showKeyboard(Activity activity) {
    View v = activity.getCurrentFocus();
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    assert imm != null && v != null;
    imm.showSoftInput(v, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Call this method to hide the soft keyboard

```
public void hideKeyBoard() {
    View view1 = this.getCurrentFocus();
    if(view!= null){
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view1.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Just *add* the following line in AndroidManifest in the specific activity.

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"/>
```

Answer (score 5):

In Kotlin, just use these two methods to show and hide the keyboard.

```
fun showKeyboard() =
    (context.getSystemService(AppCompatActivity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as? InputMethodManager)!!
        .toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0)

fun hideKeyboard(view: View) =
    (context.getSystemService(AppCompatActivity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as? InputMethodManager)!!
        .hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.windowToken, 0)
```

Here `view` is your current view.

Answer (score 4):

```
public static void hideSoftKeyboard(Activity activity) {
    InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) activity
            .getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(activity.getCurrentFocus()
            .getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

Comment: good answer, but `activity.getCurrentFocus()` can return `null`

Answer (score 4):

Try This one

```
public void disableSoftKeyboard(final EditText v) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
        v.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
        v.setTextIsSelectable(true);
    } else {
        v.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
        v.setFocusable(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

simply code :
use this code in **onCreate()**

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN
);
```

Answer (score 4):

simple method guys:
try this...

```
private void closeKeyboard(boolean b) {

        View view = this.getCurrentFocus();

        if(b) {
            if (view != null) {
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
            }
        }
        else {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.showSoftInput(view, 0);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

```
final RelativeLayout llLogin = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl_main);
        llLogin.setOnTouchListener(
                new View.OnTouchListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent ev) {
                        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) this.getSystemService(
                                Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(this.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
                        return false;
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 4):

Here are the best solutions

Solution 1) Set the inputType to “text”

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/my_edit_text"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:hint="Tap here to type"
android:inputType="text" />
```

This can also be done programmatically via. the method setInputType() (inherited from TextView).

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.my_edit_text);
editText.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | 
InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_NORMAL);
```

Solution 2) Use the InputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow()

```
InputMethodManager imm = 
(InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(myEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

or

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) 
getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(myEditText.getWindowToken(), 
InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
```

Answer (score 4):

**Very simple way**

I do this in all my projects, and work like a dream. In your declarations `layout.xml` just add this single line:

```
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

Full code example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </ListView>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 4):

When moving from fragment to fragment

```
fun hideKeyboard(activity: Activity?): Boolean {
    val inputManager = activity?.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager?
    if (inputManager != null) {
        val currentFocus = activity?.currentFocus
        if (currentFocus != null) {
            val windowToken = currentFocus.windowToken
            if (windowToken != null) {
                return inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(windowToken, 0)
            }
        }
    }
    return false
}

fun showKeyboard(editText: EditText) {
    val imm = editText.context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editText.windowToken, 0)
    imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT, 0)
    editText.requestFocus()
}
```

Comment: In [Kotlin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kotlin_(programming_language))?

Answer (score 4):

This method works if you need to hide the keyboard in a fragment.

```
public static void hideSoftKeyboard(Context context, View view) {
    if (context != null && view != null) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
}
```

For the view, just pass in the

```
getView() method
```

Answer (score 4):

Hide soft keyboard in Kotlin by creating an extension, which you can use globally. To do this, you need to create a Singleton class.

```
object Extensions {
    
      fun View.hideKeyboard() {
            val inputMethodManager =                                                 
            context.getSystemService(AppCompatActivity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)           
            as InputMethodManager
            inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(windowToken, 0)
        }
    }
```

In your activity of fragment class where you need to hide the keyboard, you can call this function with mainlayout id like below

```
//constraintEditLayout is my main view layout, if you are using other layout like relative or linear layouts you can call with that layout id
constraintEditLayout.hideKeyboard()
```

Answer (score 4):

This code will help you to hide keyboard when you touch outside the edittext or anywhere else. You need to add this code in your activity or you can write in parent activity of your project and it will also hide your keyboard in webview.

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    View v = getCurrentFocus();

    if (v != null && (ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP || ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) && v instanceof EditText &&
            !v.getClass().getName().startsWith("android.webkit.")) {
        int[] sourceCoordinates = new int[2];
        v.getLocationOnScreen(sourceCoordinates);
        float x = ev.getRawX() + v.getLeft() - sourceCoordinates[0];
        float y = ev.getRawY() + v.getTop() - sourceCoordinates[1];

        if (x < v.getLeft() || x > v.getRight() || y < v.getTop() || y > v.getBottom()) {
            hideKeyboard(this);
        }

    }
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
}

private void hideKeyboard(Activity activity) {
    if (activity != null && activity.getWindow() != null) {
        activity.getWindow().getDecorView();
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        if (imm != null) {
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(activity.getWindow().getDecorView().getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
    }
}

public static void hideKeyboard(View view) {
        if (view != null) {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) view.getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            if (imm != null)
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

For those looking for jetpack compose answer.

```
val keyboardController = LocalSoftwareKeyboardController.current

//for showing the keyboard
keyboardController?.show()
//for hiding the keyboard
keyboardController?.hide()
```

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me.

```
public static void hideKeyboard(Activity act, EditText et){
    Context c = act.getBaseContext();
    View v = et.findFocus();
    if(v == null)
        return;
    InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) c.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you can simply add this code where you want to hide the soft keyboard"

```
                        // Check if no view has focus:
                            View view = getCurrentFocus();
                            if (view != null) {
                                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
                            }
```

Answer (score 3):

In Android to hide the Vkeyboard by InputMethodManage you can cal hideSoftInputFromWindow by passing in the token of the window containing your focused view.

```
View view = this.getCurrentFocus();
if (view != null) {  
InputMethodManager im = 
(InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
im.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

By Calling editText.clearFocus() and then InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY even works

Answer (score 3):

If your application is targeting **API Level 21 or more** than there is a default method to use:

```
editTextObj.setShowSoftInputOnFocus(false);
```

Make sure you have set below code in `EditText` XML tag.

```
<EditText  
    ....
    android:enabled="true"
    android:focusable="true" />
```

Answer (score 3):

**When you want to hide keyboard manually on the action of button click:**

```
/**
 * Hides the already popped up keyboard from the screen.
 *
 */
public void hideKeyboard() {
    try {
        // use application level context to avoid unnecessary leaks.
        InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        assert inputManager != null;
        inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**When you want to hide keyboard where ever you click on screen except edittext**
Override this method in your activity:

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    View view = getCurrentFocus();
    if (view != null && (ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP || ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) && view instanceof EditText && !view.getClass().getName().startsWith("android.webkit.")) {
        int scrcoords[] = new int[2];
        view.getLocationOnScreen(scrcoords);
        float x = ev.getRawX() + view.getLeft() - scrcoords[0];
        float y = ev.getRawY() + view.getTop() - scrcoords[1];
        if (x < view.getLeft() || x > view.getRight() || y < view.getTop() || y > view.getBottom())
            ((InputMethodManager)this.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).hideSoftInputFromWindow((this.getWindow().getDecorView().getApplicationWindowToken()), 0);
    }
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Below code will help you to make generic function that can be call from anywhere.

```
import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Context
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar
import android.view.View
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager

public class KeyboardHider {
    companion object {

        fun hideKeyboard(view: View, context: Context) {
            val inputMethodManager = context.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
            inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.windowToken, 0)
        }

    }

}
```

Call Above method from anywhere using one single line of code.

```
CustomSnackbar.hideKeyboard(view, this@ActivityName)
```

view could be anything for example root layout of an activity.

Comment: Is there any difference between Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE and Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE? Both seem to work

Comment: Also, you code sample will throw IllegalStateException

Comment: @portfoliobuilder where you think that it will throw the Exception?

Comment: Lets say the user does standard implementation of hiding keyboard when app goes into background (onPause) and displaying it while in the foreground (onResume). Now lets also presume two screens. An illegalStateException can occur if keyboard is already hidden and transition occurs from Activity A to Activity B (or Fragment A to Fragment B, or Activity A to Fragment B, ect). You have no checks for if keyboard is visible already.

Answer (score 3):

just make common method for whole application in BaseActivity and BaseFragment

in `onCreate()` initialize `inputMethodManager`

```
inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
```

make this methods to hide & show keyboard

```
public void hideKeyBoard(View view) {
     if (view != null) {
         inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
      }
 }

public void showKeyboard(View view, boolean isForceToShow) {
      if (isForceToShow)
         inputMethodManager.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
      else if (view != null)
           inputMethodManager.showSoftInput(view, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I use Kotlin extensions for showing and hiding the keyboard.

```
fun View.showKeyboard() {
  this.requestFocus()
  val inputMethodManager = context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
  inputMethodManager.showSoftInput(this, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT)
}

fun View.hideKeyboard() {
  val inputMethodManager = context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
  inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(windowToken, 0)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

By adding the generic method to your utility or helper class. By just calling itself, you can hide and show the keyboard:

```
fun AppCompatActivity.hideKeyboard() {
    val view = this.currentFocus
    if (view != null) {
        val imm = getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.windowToken, 0)
    }
    window.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN)
}

fun AppCompatActivity.showKeyboard() {
    val view = this.currentFocus
    if (view != null) {
        val imm = getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.windowToken, 0)
    }
    window.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To close or hide the Android soft keyboard programmatically, you can use the following methods:

1. Using InputMethodManager:

   ```
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(yourEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
   ```
2. Using View's onEditorAction:

   If you have an EditText view and want to hide the soft keyboard when the user presses the "Done" or "Enter" key, you can use the onEditorAction listener:

   ```
    yourEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(yourEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        } });
   ```
3. Programmatically clear focus:

   Another approach is to programmatically clear focus from the EditText view, which will cause the soft keyboard to be hidden:

   ```
    yourEditText.clearFocus();
   ```

   Remember to replace yourEditText with the actual reference to your EditText view. Also, make sure you have the appropriate permissions declared in your Android manifest file, specifically android.permission.INPUT_METHOD.

These methods will allow you to programmatically hide the soft keyboard on an Android device.

Comment: This is probably the result of [plagiarism](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/plagiarism#Noun), most likely [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned) (or similar) plagiarism. It is completely out of whack with all other posts by this user.

Answer (score 2):

I created a layout partially from xml and partially from a custom layout engine, which is all handled in-code. The only thing that worked for me was to keep track of whether or not the keyboard was open, and use the keyboard toggle method as follows:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity
{
    /** This maintains true if the keyboard is open. Otherwise, it is false. */
    private boolean isKeyboardOpen = false;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        LayoutInflater inflater;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View contentView = inflater.inflate(context.getResources().getIdentifier("main", "layout", getPackageName()), null);

        setContentView(contentView);
        contentView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() 
        {
            public void onGlobalLayout() 
            {
                Rect r = new Rect();
                contentView.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r);
                int heightDiff = contentView.getRootView().getHeight() - (r.bottom - r.top);
                if (heightDiff > 100) 
                    isKeyboardVisible = true;
                else
                    isKeyboardVisible = false;
             });
         }
    }

    public void closeKeyboardIfOpen()
    {
        InputMethodManager imm;
        imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        if (isKeyboardVisible)
            imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY, 0);
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Tried all here in desperation, combining all methods,  and of course the keyboard will not close in Android 4.0.3 (it did work in Honeicomb AFAIR).

Then suddenly I found an apparently winning combination:

```
textField.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT |InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_NORMAL);
```

combined with your usual recipes

```
blahblaj.hideSoftInputFromWindow ...
```

hope this stops somebody from committing suicide .. I was close to it. Of course, I have no idea why it works.

Answer (score 2):

This method will always always work at any cost. Just Use it wherever you want to hide the keyboard

```
public static void hideSoftKeyboard(Context mContext,EditText username){
        if(((Activity) mContext).getCurrentFocus()!=null && ((Activity) mContext).getCurrentFocus() instanceof EditText){
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(username.getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
    }
```

Use it like this :

Whatever is the version of Android. This method will surely work

Answer (score 2):

```
public static void closeInput(final View caller) {  
    caller.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) caller.getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(caller.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
        }
    }, 100);
}
```

This method generally works, but there is one condition: you can't have `android:windowSoftInputMode="any_of_these"` set

Answer (score 2):

An alternative using `SearchView` would be to use this code:

```
searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();    
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new OnQueryTextListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)
        getSystemService(getApplicationContext().INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(searchView.getApplicationWindowToken(), 0);
    }
}
```

This is a SearchView search box in the ActionBar that when the text from the query is submitted (the user presses either `Enter` key or a search button/icon), then the `InputMethodManager` code gets activated and makes your soft keyboard go down. This code was put in my `onCreateOptionsMenu()`. `searchItem` is from `MenuItem` which is part of the default code for the `onCreateOptionsmenu()`. Thanks to @mckoss for a good chunk of this code!

Answer (score 2):

```
private void hideSoftKeyboard() {
    View view = getView();
    if (view != null) {
        InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getActivity()
                .getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Depite all those answers, just to be simple enough, I have written a common method to do this :

```
/**
 * hide soft keyboard in a activity
 * @param activity
 */
public static void hideKeyboard (Activity activity){
    activity.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
    if (activity.getCurrentFocus() != null) {
        InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(activity.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
/** 
 *
 *   Hide I Said!!!
 *
 */
public static boolean hideSoftKeyboard(@NonNull Activity activity) {
    View currentFocus = activity.getCurrentFocus();
    if (currentFocus == null) {
        currentFocus = activity.getWindow().getDecorView();
        if (currentFocus != null) {
            return getSoftInput(activity).hideSoftInputFromWindow(currentFocus.getWindowToken(), 0, null);
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public static boolean hideSoftKeyboard(@NonNull Context context) {
   if(Activity.class.isAssignableFrom(context.getClass())){
       return hideSoftKeyboard((Activity)context);
   }
   return false;
}

public static InputMethodManager getSoftInput(@NonNull Context context) {
    return (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can create **Extension** function for any View

```
fun View.hideKeyboard() = this.let {
    val imm = context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(windowToken, 0)
}
```

**Example use with Activity**

```
window.decorView.hideKeyboard();
```

**Example use with View**

```
etUsername.hideKeyboard();
```

Happy Coding...

Answer (score 2):

**Wiki answer in Kotlin :**

1 - Create a [top-level function](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2015/06/improving-java-interop-top-level-functions-and-properties/) inside a file (for example a file that contains all your top-level functions) :

```
fun Activity.hideKeyboard(){
    val imm = this.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
    var view = currentFocus
    if (view == null) { view = View(this) }
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.windowToken, 0)
}
```

2 - Then call it in any activity you needed it :

```
this.hideKeyboard()
```

Answer (score 2):

For the kotlin users out there here is a kotlin extension method that has worked for my use cases:

```java
fun View.hideKeyboard() {
    val imm = this.context.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(windowToken, 0)
}
```

put it in a file called ViewExtensions (or what have you) and call it on your views just like a normal method.

Answer (score 2):

```
there are two ways to do so...

method 1:in manifest file

define the line **android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateAlwaysHidden"** of code in your manifest.xml file as below...

<activity
            android:name="packagename.youactivityname"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateAlwaysHidden" />

Method 2 : in Activity or Java class

 if(getCurrentFocus()!=null) {
            InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)`enter code here`;
            inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
```

it will work....@ASK

Answer (score 2):

First, you should add from the XML file add **android:imeOptions** field and change its value to **actionUnspecified|actionGo** as below

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/edit_text_id"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/edit_text_height"
                    android:imeOptions="actionUnspecified|actionGo"
                    />
```

Then In the java class add a **setOnEditorActionListener** and add InputMethodManager as below

enterOrderNumber.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {

```
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO) {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY, 0);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This was work for me. It is in Kotlin for hiding the keyboard.

```
private fun hideKeyboard() {
        val inputManager = activity?.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
        val focusedView = activity?.currentFocus
        if (focusedView != null) {
            inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(focusedView.windowToken,
                    InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

An easy workaround is to just `editText.setEnabled(false);editText.setEnabled(true);` in your Button `onClick()` method.

Answer (score 2):

### Kotlin

```
class KeyboardUtils{
    
    companion object{
        fun hideKeyboard(activity: Activity) {
            val imm: InputMethodManager = activity.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
            var view: View? = activity.currentFocus
            if (view == null) {
                view = View(activity)
            }
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.windowToken, 0)
        }
    }
}
```

Then just call it wherever you need

### Fragments

```
KeyboardUtils.hideKeyboard(requireActivity())
```

### Activities

```
 KeyboardUtils.hideKeyboard(this)
```

Answer (score 2):

This one works for me. You just need to pass the element inside it.

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(AutocompleteviewDoctorState.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

that's Working for me

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    if (imm.isActive())
        imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

surround it with try catch, so that is keyboard is already closed, app would not crash :

```
try{

View view = this.getCurrentFocus();
if (view != null) {  
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
}catch (Exception e)
{
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You only need to write one line inside your manifest activity tag

```
 android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustPan"
```

and it will work.

Answer (score 1):

After reading all the answers above and in another post, I still didn't succeed in getting the keyboard to open automatically.

In my project I created a dialog (`AlertDialog`) dynamically (by programming it without or with minimum of needed XML).

So I was doing something like:

```
    dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);

    if(dialogBuilder==null)
        return false; //error

    inflater      = activity.getLayoutInflater();
    dialogView    = inflater.inflate(layout, null);
    ...
```

And after finishing setting-up all the views (TextView, ImageView, EditText,etc..) I did:

```
        alertDialog = dialogBuilder.create();

        alertDialog.show();
```

After playing around with all the answers I found out that most of them work ***IF*** you know ***WHERE*** to put the request... And that was the key to all.

So, the trick is to put it **BEFORE** the creation of the dialog: `alertDialog.show()` in my case, this worked like charm:

```
        alertDialog = dialogBuilder.create();           
        alertDialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);

        //And only when everything is finished - let's bring up the window - 
        alertDialog.show();

        //Viola... keyboard is waiting for you open and ready...
        //Just don't forget to request focus for the needed view (i.e. EditText..)
```

I'm quite sure this principle is the same with all windows, so pay attention to the location of your "showKeyboard" code - it should be before the window is launched.

A small request from the Android SDK dev team:

I think that all this is unnecessary as you can see thousands of programmers from all over the world are dealing with this ridiculous and trivial problem, while its solution should be clean and simple:
IMHO if I get `requestFocus()` to an input-oriented view (such as `EditText`), the keyboard should open automatically, unless the user asks not-to, so, I think the requestFocus() method is the key here and should accept boolean showSoftKeyboard with default value of `true`: `View.requestFocus(boolean showSoftKeyboard);`

Hope this will help others like me.

Answer (score 1):

Kotlin version

```
val imm: InputMethodManager = getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
//Hide:
imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY, 0);
//Show
imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT, 0);
```

Comment: Creating an extension function on `Activity` seems like a decent approach `fun Activity.closeKeyboard() {
  (getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager).apply {
    hideSoftInputFromWindow(window.decorView.windowToken, 0)
  }
}`

Answer (score 1):

Some kotlin code:

Hide keyboard from Activity:

```
(currentFocus ?: View(this))
            .apply { (getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager)
                        .hideSoftInputFromWindow(windowToken, 0) }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using following Kotlin Activity extensions:

```
/**
 * Hides soft keyboard if is open.
 */
fun Activity.hideKeyboard() {
    currentFocus?.windowToken?.let {
        (getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as? InputMethodManager?)
                ?.hideSoftInputFromWindow(it, InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS)
    }
}

/**
 * Shows soft keyboard and request focus to given view.
 */
fun Activity.showKeyboard(view: View) {
    view.requestFocus()
    currentFocus?.windowToken?.let {
        (getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as? InputMethodManager?)
                ?.showSoftInput(view, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To show keyboard on application start:

```
        getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN | WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);
        view.requestFocus();
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
            }
        }, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

For Xamarin.Android:

```
public void HideKeyboard()
{
    var imm = activity.GetSystemService(Context.InputMethodService).JavaCast<InputMethodManager>();
    var view = activity.CurrentFocus ?? new View(activity);
    imm.HideSoftInputFromWindow(view.WindowToken, HideSoftInputFlags.None);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 fun hideKeyboard(appCompatActivity: AppCompatActivity) {
        val view = appCompatActivity.currentFocus
        val imm = appCompatActivity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.windowToken, 0)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi This is simple if you are working with Kotlin i belive you can easily convert the code to Java too first in your activity use this function when your activity is load for example in the onCreate() call it.

```
fun hideKeybord (){
val inputManager = getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
if (inputManager.isAcceptingText){
    inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(currentFocus.windowToken, 0)
}
```

}

as i mentiond call this Function in your onCreate() methode then add this `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"` line to your activity in manafest.xml file Like this...

```
<activity
    android:name=".Activity.MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden">
```

Answer (score 1):

This code snippet can helped:

```
    final InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    if (inputMethodManager != null && inputMethodManager.isActive()) {
        if (getCurrentFocus() != null) {
            inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
    }
```

It can be called in different methods according to need (ex. onPause, onResume, onRestart ...)

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**:

Force fully the Android soft input keyboard:

#### Create a method in a helper class

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
if (imm != null)
    imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
```

Answer (score 1):

This works in a fragment with [Android 10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_10) (API 29):

```
val activityView = activity?.window?.decorView?.rootView
activityView?.let {
    val imm = activity?.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as? InputMethodManager
    imm?.hideSoftInputFromWindow(it.windowToken, 0)
}
```

Comment: What is that? [Kotlin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kotlin_(programming_language))?

Answer (score 1):

You can hide the keyboard in Kotlin as well using this code snippet.

```
 fun hideKeyboard(activity: Activity?) {
    val inputManager: InputMethodManager? = 
    activity?.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as? 
    InputMethodManager
    // Check if no view has focus:
    val v = activity?.currentFocus ?: return
    inputManager?.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.windowToken, 0)
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a new API in Android 11 called `WindowInsetsController`. Apps can get access to a controller from any view, by which we can use the `hide()` and `show()` methods:

```
val controller = view.windowInsetsController

// Show the keyboard (IME)
controller.show(Type.ime())

// Hide the keyboard
controller.hide(Type.ime())
```

See *[WindowInsetsController](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowInsetsController)*

Answer (score 1):

````
 //In Activity
        View v = this.getCurrentFocus();
        if (v != null) {
            InputMethodManager im = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            im.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
        }


//In Fragment
        View v = getActivity().getCurrentFocus();
        if (v != null) {
            InputMethodManager im = (InputMethodManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            im.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
```
````

Answer (score 1):

If you set in your `.xml` android:focused="true", then it would not work, because it is a set like it is not changeable.

So the solution:

android:focusedByDefault="true"

Then it will set it once and can hide or show the keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the easiest way to hide the soft keyboard with Kotlin:

```
//hides soft keyboard anything else is tapped( screen, menu bar, buttons, etc. )
override fun dispatchTouchEvent( ev: MotionEvent? ): Boolean {
    if ( currentFocus != null ) {
        val imm = getSystemService( Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE ) as InputMethodManager
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow( currentFocus!!.windowToken, 0 )
    }
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent( ev )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget: In system settings of smartphone is in "Input methods and Languages -> Physical keyboard -> Show OnScreen Keyboard -> On/Off". This settings "interfere" all programming solutions which are here! I had to disable/enable this settings too for complete hide/show onscreen keyboard! Because I am developing for device MC2200 I did it with "EMDK Profile manage -> Ui manager -> Virtual Keyboard state -> Show/Hide"

Answer (score 1):

I tried this. Works well, tested on Nougat API 24.

```
import android.app.Activity
import androidx.core.view.WindowCompat
import androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsCompat
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment


fun Activity.hideKeyboard() {
    getInsetController().hide((WindowInsetsCompat.Type.ime()))
}

fun Activity.showKeyboard() {
    getInsetController().show((WindowInsetsCompat.Type.ime()))
}

fun Fragment.hideKeyboard() {
    requireActivity().getInsetController().hide((WindowInsetsCompat.Type.ime()))
}

fun Fragment.showKeyboard() {
    requireActivity().getInsetController().show((WindowInsetsCompat.Type.ime()))
}

fun Activity.getInsetController() = WindowCompat.getInsetsController(window, window.decorView)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried all of solutions very much but no solution work for me, so I found my solution:
You should have boolean variables like:

```
public static isKeyboardShowing = false;
InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getActivity()
            .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
```

And in a touch screen event you call:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if(keyboardShowing==true){
        inputMethodManager.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.RESULT_UNCHANGED_HIDDEN, 0);
        keyboardShowing = false;
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

And in EditText is in anywhere:

```
yourEditText.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            yourClass.keyboardShowing = true;

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in Kotlin

```
 private fun hideKeyboard(){
    val imm = activity!!.getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(activity!!.currentFocus!!.windowToken, 0)
}
```

Try this in Java

```
 private void hideKeyboard(){
  InputMethodManager imm =(InputMethodManager)getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
  imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void hideKeyboard() 
{
    if(getCurrentFocus()!=null) 
    {
        InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
}


public void showKeyboard(View mView) {
    InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    mView.requestFocus();
    inputMethodManager.showSoftInput(mView, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of answers. If after all nothing works then, here is a tip :),

You can make an EditText and,

```
edittext.setAlpha(0f);
```

this edittext will not be seen because of the alpha method.
Now use the Above answers on how to show/hide soft keyboard with EditText.

Answer (score 0):

```
public final class UtilsKeyboard {
/**
 * Sets the cursor at the end of this edit text and shows a keyboard
 */
public static void focusKeyboard(@NonNull EditText editText) {
    editText.requestFocus();
    editText.setSelection(editText.getText().length());
    showKeyboard(editText);
}

private static void showKeyboard(@NonNull View view) {
    final InputMethodManager manager = (InputMethodManager) view.getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    if (manager != null) {
        manager.showSoftInput(view, InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);
    }
}

public static boolean hideKeyboard(@NonNull Window window) {
    View view = window.getCurrentFocus();
    return hideKeyboard(window, view);
}

private static boolean hideKeyboard(@NonNull Window window, @Nullable View view) {
    if (view == null) {
        return false;
    }
    InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) window.getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    if (inputMethodManager != null) {
        return inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
    return false;
}

public static boolean hideKeyboard(@Nullable View view) {
    if (view == null) {
        return false;
    }
    InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) view.getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    if (inputMethodManager != null) {
        return inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
    return false;
}

/**
 * This will hide the keyboard and unfocus any focused view.
 */
public static void unfocusKeyboard(@NonNull Window window) {
    // When showing the bottom menu, make sure the keyboard isn't and that no view has focus
    hideKeyboard(window);
    final View focused = window.getCurrentFocus();
    if (focused != null) focused.clearFocus();
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

Construct it with an activity (a view is optional), use a handler to post this (with some delay, for example, 100 ms is better).
Directly calling the input manager will not work sometimes.
It only works while we can get the Activity. I think it is normal.

If you can get your root viewgroup or editview when you call. Just send it in for a better result.

```
public class CloseSoftKeyboardRunnable implements Runnable
{
    Activity activity;
    View view;  // For dialog will occur context getcurrentfocus == null. send a rootview to find currentfocus.

    public CloseSoftKeyboardRunnable(Activity activity, View view)
    {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.view = view;
    }

    public CloseSoftKeyboardRunnable(Activity activity)
    {
        this.activity = activity;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (!activity.isFinishing())
        {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)activity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

            if (view == null) {
                view = activity.getCurrentFocus();
            }
            else
            {
                try {
                    view = ((ViewGroup)view).getFocusedChild();
                }
                catch ( Exception e) {}
            }

            Window window =  activity.getWindow();

            if (window != null)
            {
                if (view == null) {
                    try {
                        view = window.getDecorView();
                        view = ((ViewGroup)view).getFocusedChild();
                    }
                    catch ( Exception e) {}
                }

                if (view == null) {
                    view = window.getDecorView();
                }

                if (view != null) {
                    if (view instanceof EditText)
                    {
                        EditText edittext = ((EditText) view);
                        edittext.setText(edittext.getText().toString()); // Reset edit text bug on some keyboards bug
                        edittext.clearFocus();
                    }

                    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
                }
                window.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin Version:

```
fun showKeyboard(mEtSearch: EditText, context: Context) {
        mEtSearch.requestFocus()
        val imm: InputMethodManager =
            context.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
        imm.showSoftInput(mEtSearch, 0)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the extensions below to hide and show the soft keyboard:

```
fun Fragment.showKeyboard(view: View) {
    view.isFocusableInTouchMode = true
    view.requestFocus()
    val imm = view.context?.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)
        as InputMethodManager
    imm.showSoftInput(view, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT) }

fun Fragment.hideKeyboard(view: View) {
    view.clearFocus()
    val imm = view.context?.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)
       as InputMethodManager
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.windowToken, 0) }
```

To call the extension, you can simply follow the below in your fragments:

```
showKeyboard(Your edittext ID)

hideKeboard(Your edittext ID)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add OnFocusChangeListener to the your view. For example, editText in this case.

```
editText.onFocusChangeListener = View.OnFocusChangeListener { _, hasFocus ->
        if (!hasFocus) {
           val imm = getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
           val focusedView = currentFocus
           if (imm != null && focusedView != null) {
              imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(focusedView.windowToken, 0)
           }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are various methods to do that, some of them are-

**1.) Using Toggle soft input**

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY, 0);
```

**2.) Using view**

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) view.getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

**3.) Using clearFocus()**

```
editText.clearFocus();
```

**Overall your code will look like this,**

```
public class YourActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText editText;
    private Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);

        editText = findViewById(R.id.editText);
        button = findViewById(R.id.button);
 
        View rootLayout = findViewById(R.id.rootLayout); // Replace with the ID of your root layout
        rootLayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    hideKeyboard();
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
 
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) { 
            }
        });
    }

    private void hideKeyboard() {
        View view = this.getCurrentFocus();
        if (view != null) {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

An easy way for you is to set the below attribute in your EditText View.

```
android:imeOptions="actionDone"
```

Answer (score -6):

This works for me :

```
 @Override
 public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
View v = getCurrentFocus();
boolean ret = super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);

if (v instanceof EditText) {
    View w = getCurrentFocus();
    int scrcoords[] = new int[2];
    w.getLocationOnScreen(scrcoords);
    float x = event.getRawX() + w.getLeft() - scrcoords[0];
    float y = event.getRawY() + w.getTop() - scrcoords[1];

    Log.d("Activity",
            "Touch event " + event.getRawX() + "," + event.getRawY()
                    + " " + x + "," + y + " rect " + w.getLeft() + ","
                    + w.getTop() + "," + w.getRight() + ","
                    + w.getBottom() + " coords " + scrcoords[0] + ","
                    + scrcoords[1]);
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP
            && (x < w.getLeft() || x >= w.getRight() || y < w.getTop() || y > w
                    .getBottom())) {

        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getWindow().getCurrentFocus()
                .getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
}
return ret;
}
```

Answer (score -10):

Just add this property in your `EditTect` view to hide the keyboard.

```
android:focusable="false"
```

Comment: You're just throwing darts, and this one not only missed the board, but almost hit the bartender.